# Why I cannot use eval(entire_string) straightaway, why do I need to use parser.expr(entire_string).compile()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, eval

[Source code for building a calculator using Tkinter](https://pastebin.com/WF37tWgp)

`parser.expr(entire_string).compile()` **VS** `eval(entire_string)`

Version1:

```
import parser
entire_string = '1+2'
a = parser.expr(entire_string).compile()
result = eval(a)
```

Version2:

```
entire_string = '1+2'
result = eval(entire_string)
```

What is the point of using `parser.expr(entire_string).compile()` , why not use `eval(entire_string)` straight away?

Comment: What do you mean when you say you cannot use `eval(entire_string)`? It is valid code

Comment: I do n understand what is parser.expr(entire_string).compile() used for? Why do I need it for? What is the point of using it?

Comment: Where did you get this from? Do you have an online tutorial or similar that gave you this information?

Comment: Yes online  tutorial:https://www.udemy.com/course/python-masterclass-course/

Comment: I don't see a reason for this; either the tutorial you got the code from explains it, or I think it's just unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because eval in python is dangerous. If the string is input by the user, then they can execute arbitrary code on your machine. This is particularly dangerous if it's running on a remote server.

The parser will parse just an expression and return a value without allowing arbitrary python code to run.